# Check role of Username then echo something if administrator

Tags: user-roles, user-meta

I am stumped on something I have been working on and would really appreciate any help you can offer.

The code below is what elements are to be displayed on a job note. It currently has the users avatar, username, date created and the comment. Both users and administrators(co-workers) can use the notes. If the username of the comment is Administrator then next to it display "- expert". But if the username of the comment is not Administrator role then it will not display anything next to it.

```
<?php ?><div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Comment">
<div class="gv-note-author-details" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">
    <div class="gv-note-avatar" itemprop="image">{avatar}</div>
    <h6 class="gv-note-author" itemprop="name">{user_name} <?php if { echo "Echo expert title here";} else { "echo nothing"}}?></h6>
</div>
<span class="gv-note-added-on" itemprop="dateCreated" datetime="{date_created}">{added_on}</span>
<div class="gv-note-content" itemprop="comment">{value}</div>
```

The only thing I see online that references this is get_current_user but I don't want it to get current user. I want it to simple check if username is Administrator then echo "- expert"; else echo "echo nothing";

Note {user_name} is display name of user

Comment: What's the connection with WordPress?

Comment: In case this is helpful here is the file that determines what {user_name} is:
http://codex.gravityview.co/class-gravityview-entry-notes_8php_source.html

Comment: Gravity Forms is not a part of WordPress. The syntax you use is not WordPress' own also.

Answer (score 2):

@terminator answer might work but there's no need to create an array and use array_intersect I think since you're only looking for one role. This might be more comprehensible:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$roles = (array) $current_user->roles;
if (in_array('administrator', $roles) { /* echo whatever */ }
```

Don't forget to check that 'administrator' is acutally the role key you want.

Comment: In case this is helpful here is the file that determines what {user_name} is:
http://codex.gravityview.co/class-gravityview-entry-notes_8php_source.html

Comment: Sorry I don't see the link between your question and GravityView ? And do you have additional questions ?

Answer (score 1):

Both Bbackerry and terminator didn't read properly. The OP asked: "I want it to simple check if username is Administrator then echo "- expert"; else echo "echo nothing";". Which is the following code:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( $current_user->user_login == 'Administrator' ) {
    echo '- expert';
} else {
    echo "echo nothing";
}
```

Comment: Hey Beee, 

I tested it and it didn't work :/ It was just echoing "echo nothing" everytime. 

Would I need to add a get_currentuserinfo(); in there somewhere?

Comment: To be honest, I never use wp_get_current_user, I always use get_userdata( get_current_user_id() ). get_currentuserinfo is depracated. BUT it is better to check if a user has certain capabilities instead of checking for a username, since a username can be changed and then your code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Please keep in mind the comparison for user name is caps sensitive.

Comment: The thing I still see wrong is the snippet you provided checks the if the current user is logged in correct? But there is nothing comparing it to the (user_name}. I am still very new to backend stuff as I am a frontend guy but Im wondering if there is a way to make it like this so that get current user could work:

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
If user name = administrator and is current user logged in then echo something else echo nothing. Does that make sense?

Comment: In case this is helpful here is the file that determines what {user_name} is:
http://codex.gravityview.co/class-gravityview-entry-notes_8php_source.html

Comment: I have just tested my own code but changed it to my name. It does exactly what you want it to do. It checks whether the current user's user name/login equals the string you provided. If so, it echoes "-expert". A user is always logged in, otherwise it's a visitor.

Comment: I think we were talking about different things... {user_name} is not the user name of a registered user, but an input from a gravity form ? Is that correct ?

Comment: Okay I see where the confusion is! So the code I pasted above echo's {user_name} so the user's display name of who created the note. The script is the template for the note so the information changes based on what was entered.

I don't want to check to see if the users name is Administrator. I want to see if the array {user_name} is role Administrator and if it is then echo "- Expert" and if the user role is not Administrator and in this case Subscriber then echo nothing.

Is something like that even possible?

Comment: I feel really bad for taking up your time on this but I really need help with it! haha

Comment: It might be, but I think you have described the problem too little. Where does this code appear ? Because I feel it's inside a code from Gravity and then this is not the place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think this  might work for you

```
$username = "terminator";
$user = get_user_by('login',$username); 
if(in_array('administrator',$user->roles )){    
    echo "Echo expert";
}else{
    echo "nothing";
}
```

Let me know how it goes
thanks

Comment: Hey Terminator, as Beee mentioned above I am not trying to get current user I am trying to check is {user_name} is role administrator or not. If you have any ideas on that it would be much appreciated!

Comment: In case this is helpful here is the file that determines what {user_name} is:
http://codex.gravityview.co/class-gravityview-entry-notes_8php_source.html

Comment: @Kevin W. Please see the update answer

Comment: Okay I see where the confusion is! So the code I pasted above echo's {user_name} so the user's display name of who created the note. The script is the template for the note so the information changes based on what was entered.

I don't want to check to see if the users name is Administrator. I want to see if the array {user_name} is role Administrator and if it is then echo "- Expert" and if the user role is not Administrator and in this case Subscriber then echo nothing.

Is something like that even possible?

Comment: I feel really bad for taking up your time on this but I really need help with it! haha

Comment: @Kevin W. there is no way to do that .. I just saw {user_name} is display name..  display name is not a unique key means .... Different user may have the same display name .....  We can only know the role of user base on these user ID, slug, email address, or login name   ....  SO if this is not available then I am afraid I can't help..  you need to tweak the original code .. and get some other value along with the display name